# What languages do I need to know if I want to work with Kendo UI from Telerik?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, telerik, kendo-ui

If I want to work with **Kendo UI** from **Telerik**, what languages do I need to know beside ( HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, C#)?

E.g. Jquery, Json, Ruby on rails, others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the http://www.kendoui.com/faq/faq.aspx "Kendo UI is a pure JavaScript framework" and "Kendo UI can be used with (or without) any server-side technology... Kendo UI only requires jQuery." So you must know JavaScript and jQuery and you may know HTML5, CSS and some sort of server technology (ASP.NET, PHP, etc.)

Comment: I'm using kendo UI now, and it's very much like jQuery UI. You will need to know some kind of server side language to incorporate it with your data, but to just display static data you won't need to know anything but javaScript and jQuery.